# Double checking my progress on finding critical numbers

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

still cramming for the test tomorrow. (This cram has lasted most of my weekend) I'm having trouble with determining the critical values for this example problem. The problem is as follows:

$$F(x) = x^{\frac{4}{5}}(x-4)^2$$

I'm sort of fuzzy with finding critical numbers and I don't have a solution to this in my book so I figured I would walk you guys through my steps and someone might be kind enough to tell me if I got the right answers and if not to help me get back on the right track. :3

I first take the derivative using the product rule:

$$F'(x) = \frac{4(x-4)^2}{5x^{\frac{1}{5}}} + 2(x-4) * x^{\frac{4}{5}}$$

I end up multiplying the right hand side by $5x^{\frac{1}{5}}$ and combining the terms.

$$\frac{4(x-4)^2 + 2(x-4) * x^{\frac{4}{5}} * 5x^{\frac{1}{5}}}{5x^{\frac{1}{5}}}$$

I further combine the terms:

$$\frac{4(x-4)^2 + 12x(x-4)}{5x^{\frac{1}{5}}}$$

Then I factor out a $4(x-4)$ and get:

$$\frac{4(x-4)[(x-4) + 3x]}{5x^{\frac{1}{5}}}$$

The derivative is zero or undefined when:

$$5x^{\frac{1}{5}} = 0$$
$$4(x-4) = 0$$
$$x – 4 + 3x = 0$$

So my critical numbers are: **4, 1, and 0**.

What do you guys think?

Comment: It is $10x(x-4)$, not $12x(x-4)$.

Comment: Looks good after you fix the mistake that @AndréNicolas has observed.

Answer (score 2):

In light of @Andre's comment, let's do the differentiation again:
$$[x^{4/5} (x-4)^2]'=(x^{4/5})' (x-4)^2+x^{4/5}((x-4)^2)'=\frac{4}5x^{-1/5}(x-4)^2+x^{4/5}(2x-8)$$ $$=\frac{2(x-4)(7x-8)}{5x^{1/5}}$$ Now find the wanted points. Indeed, they are $x=0, x=+4, x=8/7$.